# How to remove double codes using Mulesoft

Tags: soap, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to compare SOAP action header with request url using mule 4. But SOAP action header coming with double quotes. Bcz of that both url are not match. I want remove these double codes or compare only string thing in mule 4.
attributes.headers.soapaction="http://test.com/test/addEmp"

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var requestUrl='http://test.com/test/addEmp'
---
attributes.headers.soapaction == requestUrl
```

Comment: Would be good if you can post in your question as to what does `attributes.headers.soapaction` return?

Comment: Hi @salim attributes.headers.soapaction="http://test.com/test/addEmp"        bcz of these double codes it's not matching with var requestUrl

Comment: Your `attributes.headers.soapaction`  is missing http: and thus your comparison is failing. I have updated the answer to show you the same. The quotes single or double shouldn't really matter as both can be used to define a string and they help set the bounds on the definition.

Comment: I get soap action header from request. By default it's coming with double codes. If I add additional " " to var requestUr It's matching. It's compare with " " also.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are receiving an HTTP request or response with a SOAP payload but with duplicated SOAPAction HTTP header, and you want to remove the duplicates that don't match a given value for the header. You can try a Transform that targets the attribute and use filterObject() to remove the incorrect duplicates:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{ 
   headers: attributes.headers filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key as String == "soapaction" and value == "http://test.com/test/addEmp")
}
```

Note that this will remove other attributes as well and leave only HTTP headers. Depending on what you are doing it may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var a = "some text"
var b = 'some text'
---
a == b
```

```
%dw 2.0
var requestUrl='http://test.com/test/addEmp'
var soapaction="http://test.com/test/addEmp"
//instead of the variable (soapaction)  defined above, you can refer to it through attributes. 
---
requestUrl == soapaction
```

[image]